# Why does R think all of my rows end in "e"?

Tags: r, dplyr, melt, ends-with

I am trying to create a new column with information from another column. For example, I want "Neutrophil_A0Late" to have "Late" in a new column, and "Neutrophil_A0Peak" to have "Peak" in the new column. My current code is:

```
gene_CNS <- melt(gene_CNS)
mutate(gene_CNS, timepoint = case_when(
  endsWith("variable", "k") ~ "Peak",
  endsWith("variable", "e") ~ "Late",
  endsWith("variable", "l") ~ "Preclinical",
  endsWith("variable", "t") ~ "Onset"))
```

and it spits out:

```
   X1                         variable       value timepoint
1   Mertk               Neutrophils_A0Late 0.008430985      Late
2   Mertk              Neutrophils_A0Onset 0.000000000      Late
3   Mertk               Neutrophils_A0Peak 0.000000000      Late
4   Mertk        Neutrophils_A0Preclinical 0.000000000      Late
```

Clearly it thinks all of my "variable" entries end in "e", and I'm not sure why. Can anyone help? Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Because you have "variable" in quotes and that string ends in "e". If you want to use the column, do not use quotes. For example `endsWith(variable, "k")`

Comment: Do all your entries in `variable` begin with `"Neutrophil_A0"`, or with some common format?  If so, these could likely be handled extensibly in a single line, using a `mutate()` and regex.

Comment: When I try removing the quotes around variable, I end up with this error: 
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `timepoint`.
x non-character object(s)
ℹ Input `timepoint` is `case_when(...)`.

Comment: Then it sounds like your "variable" column is probably a factor rather than a character value and `endsWith` doesn't automatically convert to character. Are you suing R 4.0 or newer? Normally you have to explictly set to factor now. But you can do `endsWith(as.character(variable), "k")` to change it back, or you could transform the column once before doing all those checks

Comment: Thank you!!! The as.character function worked!

Comment: If that comment solved your question you can post an answer incorporating it ...[

Comment: Given your data, this would be simpler: `gene_CNS$timepoint <- gsub("Neutrophils_A0", "", gene_CNS$variable)`.